# AWS Amplify Auth - The requested module does not provide an export named 'Auth'

Tags: vue.js, aws-amplify

Trying to build an AWS Amplify app using VueJS.

```
amplify add auth
amplify push
amplify env pull dev
```

I added an Auth module, authentication works based on an [example](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/vue/connected-components/authenticator) using the `authenticator` tag

```
import { Authenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-vue";

<authenticator>
  <template v-slot="{ user, signOut }">
  ...
```

I'm trying to get the OAuth user token to call other services, I recall there was an object *Auth*, which provided as well some methods getting the user details

Howevere when following some [guides](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-authentication-to-a-vue-app-using-aws-amplify/)

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
```

The application fails to display and the browser logs an exception:

> App.vue:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/aws-amplify.js?v=ec6e723f' does not provide an export named 'Auth' (at App.vue:4:10)

How do I get the Auth object .. or the OAuth token?

Edit:

> amplify --version: 12.8.2 
> "aws-amplify": "^6.0.5"

I managed to get the access_token, yet I'm not sure if this is the correct/best approach

```
import { fetchAuthSession } from 'aws-amplify/auth;

onMounted( async() => {
try {
  console.log("AUTH: "+ JSON.stringify(await fetchAuthSession() ));
} catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
}  })
```

Comment: Try to use `import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';` then use `Amplify.Auth`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim  `Amplify.Auth` is undefined :(

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: package.json: `"vue": "^3.2.45"`

Comment: I mean aws-amplify

Comment: `amplify --version:` 12.8.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256082/discussion-between-gusto2-and-boussadjra-brahim).

Comment: You found in the package.json, in my case is version 5, the latest one is 6

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on the Amplify API documentation:
https://docs.amplify.aws/vue/build-a-backend/restapi/customize-authz/

```
import { fetchAuthSession } from 'aws-amplify/auth'
...
const authToken = (await fetchAuthSession()).tokens?.idToken?.toString();
```